# How to render zero-width glyphs in ttf?

Tags: truetype, typography

I'm working on a TrueType font parsing/rendering engine in Javascript.  Source can be found [here](https://github.com/samlecuyer/fontificate).

My problem is that the `space` glyph is almost always indexed in the `loca` table as zero-width, which means that when I look up the glyph in the `loca` offsets, I get the offset for the `exclam` glyph.  The [spec for the loca table](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6loca.html) says:

> If the font does not contain an outline for the missing character, then the first and second offsets should have the same value. This also applies to any other character without an outline, such as the space character. If a glyph has no outline, its length should be zero.

So, it looks like the space character has no outline, but I don't want to draw the `.notdef` glyph.  How do I decide what to draw (or at least offset horizontally) if there's no glyph outline set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This width of a character is set in the `hmtx` table, and a glyph must be rendered in that width, regardless of whether or not there is an outline defined for it.

Answer (score 1):

The glyph is not zero-width - it is defined by zero bytes.  You draw nothing for it.  The advance width is defined in other tables, typically hmtx.  Advanced typography controls may modify this advance width, as for other glyphs.